# System won't boot because it thinks it has dependency on sshfs mounts

Tags: boot, mount, sshfs

I have a desktop running Ubuntu 20.04. I typically keep `/mnt/wdblue4a` and `/mnt/wdblue4b` mounted with sshfs, just with a script I run manually if I want to access their content. This has never been a problem before, but now, upon trying to reboot, the system is refusing to boot up.

[image: boot text]

It only gets to this point after a delay, and then doesn't progress further. I can't even type input into the shell.

How can I fix this issue and get my system to boot, and prevent this from re-ocurring? Thanks.

Comment: If you have your Ubuntu installation USB stick, you can “Try Ubuntu” and check the contents of `/etc/fstab` to see if the wdblue devices are listed there. If they are, comment the lines out with a `#` at the start and then try to boot normally 

Comment: @matigo Rather than #-commenting the entry, simply remove "`auto`" keyword from it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to boot into recovery mode and tried commenting out these entries as suggested in the comments, but it still didn't boot. Eventually I resorted to backing up my files, and reinstalling Ubuntu while keeping my old files. Thanks for the help everyone.